Cloudinary variables not working in .env file
I have a NextJs application using a express backend api.  I'm trying to upload user avatars to a folder in cloudinary.  I have the cloudinar.js file with the cloudinary.config file that I call from the userController.  If I enter the cloud_name, api_key, and api_secret directly in the cloudinary.config file, it works with no trouble, but if I move the variables to a .env file, and call them with process.env.CLOUD_NAME I get the following error saying I must supply cloud_name:
Error: Must supply api_key
[0]     at ensureOption (C:\Users\judo2\Documents\dev\my-sites\the_mat_house\mat_scout_nextjs\node_modules\cloudinary\lib\utils\ensureOption.js:19:13)
[0]     at Object.sign_request (C:\Users\judo2\Documents\dev\my-sites\the_mat_house\mat_scout_nextjs\node_modules\cloudinary\lib\utils\index.js:1164:16)
[0]     at Object.process_request_params (C:\Users\judo2\Documents\dev\my-sites\the_mat_house\mat_scout_nextjs\node_modules\cloudinary\lib\utils\index.js:1214:22)
[0]     at call_api (C:\Users\judo2\Documents\dev\my-sites\the_mat_house\mat_scout_nextjs\node_modules\cloudinary\lib\uploader.js:474:18)
[0]     at Object.upload (C:\Users\judo2\Documents\dev\my-sites\the_mat_house\mat_scout_nextjs\node_modules\cloudinary\lib\uploader.js:53:10)
[0]     at Object.upload (C:\Users\judo2\Documents\dev\my-sites\the_mat_house\mat_scout_nextjs\node_modules\cloudinary\lib\utils\index.js:1411:21)
[0]     at file:///C:/Users/judo2/Documents/dev/my-sites/the_mat_house/mat_scout_nextjs/server/controllers/userController.js:262:46
[0]     at file:///C:/Users/judo2/Documents/dev/my-sites/the_mat_house/mat_scout_nextjs/server/middleware/asyncHandler.js:2:19
[0]     at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\judo2\Documents\dev\my-sites\the_mat_house\mat_scout_nextjs\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
[0]     at next (C:\Users\judo2\Documents\dev\my-sites\the_mat_house\mat_scout_nextjs\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:149:13)
[0] Error: Must supply api_key
[0]     at ensureOption (C:\Users\judo2\Documents\dev\my-sites\the_mat_house\mat_scout_nextjs\node_modules\cloudinary\lib\utils\ensureOption.js:19:13)
[0]     at Object.sign_request (C:\Users\judo2\Documents\dev\my-sites\the_mat_house\mat_scout_nextjs\node_modules\cloudinary\lib\utils\index.js:1164:16)
[0]     at Object.process_request_params (C:\Users\judo2\Documents\dev\my-sites\the_mat_house\mat_scout_nextjs\node_modules\cloudinary\lib\utils\index.js:1214:22)
[0]     at call_api (C:\Users\judo2\Documents\dev\my-sites\the_mat_house\mat_scout_nextjs\node_modules\cloudinary\lib\uploader.js:474:18)
[0]     at Object.upload (C:\Users\judo2\Documents\dev\my-sites\the_mat_house\mat_scout_nextjs\node_modules\cloudinary\lib\uploader.js:53:10)
[0]     at Object.upload (C:\Users\judo2\Documents\dev\my-sites\the_mat_house\mat_scout_nextjs\node_modules\cloudinary\lib\utils\index.js:1411:21)
[0]     at file:///C:/Users/judo2/Documents/dev/my-sites/the_mat_house/mat_scout_nextjs/server/controllers/userController.js:262:46
[0]     at file:///C:/Users/judo2/Documents/dev/my-sites/the_mat_house/mat_scout_nextjs/server/middleware/asyncHandler.js:2:19
[0]     at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\judo2\Documents\dev\my-sites\the_mat_house\mat_scout_nextjs\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
[0]     at next (C:\Users\judo2\Documents\dev\my-sites\the_mat_house\mat_scout_nextjs\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:149:13)

I tried String(process.env.CLOUD_NAME) and I get the error that cloud_name is disabled, but again, if I enter the cloud name directly into the config object, it works.
My .enf file works because It is getting the MONGO_URI from the .env file
I am initializing dotenv in the server.js file:
import dotenv from "dotenv";
dotenv.config();
Here is the cloudinar.js file:
import { v2 as cloudinary } from "cloudinary";

// Configuration
cloudinary.config({
  cloud_name: process.env.CLOUD_NAME,
  api_key: process.env.CLOUD_KEY,
  api_secret: process.env.CLOUD_SECRET, // Click 'View API Keys' above to copy your API secret
});

export default cloudinary;

And here is the part of the userController where I call cloudinary:
const result = await cloudinary.uploader.upload(image, {
      folder: "products",
      // width: 300,
      // crop: "scale"
    });


Can you try importing dotenv in cloudinar.js let us know if that works? I believe the import of dotenv may be scoped to just server.js and not any imported scripts.

Wow, that did it.  Thank you so much.  I've never had to do that beofore.  If you give that as an answer I'll accept it.  Thanks again!

Looks like this is an issue of scope, so you should be able to resolve it by importing and configuring dotenv within cloudinar.js
